# Click and drag scroll to have momentum when releasing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

Two things I need are that you could choose the speed of the scroll when dragging and upon release it would still move a bit, not stop instantly.

**codepen:** https://codepen.io/rKaiser/pen/qGomdR

I can set the speed close enough. Reasonable to add some momentum? or perhaps there is a more fitting plugin to use here? Thanks.

```
const slider = document.querySelector('.container');
let isDown = false;
let startX;
let scrollLeft;
slider.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  isDown = true;
  slider.classList.add('active');
  startX = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
  scrollLeft = slider.scrollLeft;
});
slider.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
  isDown = false;
  slider.classList.remove('active');
});
slider.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
  isDown = false;
  slider.classList.remove('active');
});
slider.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  if(!isDown) return;
  e.preventDefault();
  const x = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
  const walk = (x - startX) * 0.3; //scroll-speed
  slider.scrollLeft = scrollLeft - walk;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase scrollLeft with certain amount with every frame, after mouseup, till speed becomes 0. Something like=>

```
slider.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
  isDown = false;
  slider.classList.remove('active');
  speed = (-scrollLeft+slider.scrollLeft)/(new Date()-t)*500; //t is time of mouse down start

  const draw=()=>{
    if(speed>0){
      slider.scrollLeft = slider.scrollLeft + speed--; //increase by certain amount
    }else{
      momentum=false;
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  }
    momentum=true;
    draw();
});



slider.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  if(!isDown && !momentum){
    return;
  }..
```